# How can I insert and display copyright owner field on featured-images, pictures and galleries in articles?

Tags: wordpress

My request is to provide a separate copyright field for images and to display the copyright information for each image. For this purpose I have inserted a separate field in the media library based on this source (https://bavotasan.com/2012/add-a-copyright-field-to-the-media-uploader-in-wordpress/)

```
/**
 * Adding a "Copyright" field to the media uploader $form_fields array
 *
 * @param array $form_fields
 * @param object $post
 *
 * @return array
 */
function add_copyright_field_to_media_uploader( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $form_fields['copyright_field'] = array(
        'label' => __('Copyright'),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_copyright', true ),
        'helps' => 'Set a copyright credit for the attachment'
    );

    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'add_copyright_field_to_media_uploader', null, 2 );

/**
 * Save our new "Copyright" field
 *
 * @param object $post
 * @param object $attachment
 *
 * @return array
 */
function add_copyright_field_to_media_uploader_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if ( ! empty( $attachment['copyright_field'] ) ) 
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_custom_copyright', $attachment['copyright_field'] );
    else
        delete_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_custom_copyright' );

    return $post;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'add_copyright_field_to_media_uploader_save', null, 2 );

/**
 * Display our new "Copyright" field
 *
 * @param int $attachment_id
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_featured_image_copyright( $attachment_id = null ) {
    $attachment_id = ( empty( $attachment_id ) ) ? get_post_thumbnail_id() : (int) $attachment_id;

    if ( $attachment_id )
        return get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_custom_copyright', true );

}
```

With the above code in place, you can now use the following snippet to display your attachment’s new “Copyright” field within one of your page templates.

```
<?php echo get_featured_image_copyright(); ?>
```

Unfortunately, this snippet is only available for featured-images.
How can I use this snippet for images and galleries within articles? Would that work with the codebase? If not, how would you solve this problem without plugins? I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a parameter in the function   `get_featured_image_copyright($attachment_id);`.

So you can call the function with an image id :

`get_featured_image_copyright($image_id);`.

Example with a gallery:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
     if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
            $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );

            /* Loop through all the image and output copyright one by one */
            foreach( $gallery['ids'] as $id ) : 
              echo get_featured_image_copyright($id);
            endforeach;
     endif;
endwhile;
```

No tested but you get the idea and i'm pretty sure i didn't made any typo

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I put it in the single.php loop. Unfortunately the copyright entries are not shown on the images.